# I got an error in a function call of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I got an unexpected error while doing a function call in C using the array, I know a little bit of C and I don't understand how I can fix it. The code of the main function is attached below.

```
void sum_matrices (int m1[][NUM_COLS], int m2[][NUM_COLS], int num_rows, int result[][NUM_COLS]);
void print_matrix (int m[][NUM_COLS], int num_rows);
void print_array (int a[], int len);

int main(void) {

    int my_matrix_1[][NUM_COLS] = {{1, 5, 3, 4, 2},
                                   {7, 1, 4, 1, 7},
                                   {6, 9, 2, 0, 5}};
    int my_matrix_2[][NUM_COLS] = {{7, 8, 3, 3, 4},
                                   {1, 3, 7, 8, 2},
                                   {1, 3, 5, 6, 0}};
    int num_rows = 3;
    int result[num_rows][NUM_COLS]; // finish this line of code to create the result matrix to pass to sum_matrices

    // add call to sum_matrices to add my_matrix_1 and my_matrix_2

    sum_matrices (my_matrix_1[][NUM_COLS], my_matrix_2[][NUM_COLS], num_rows, result[][NUM_COLS]);

    print_matrix(my_matrix_1, num_rows);
    printf("\n");
    print_matrix(my_matrix_2, num_rows);
    printf("\n");
    print_matrix(result, num_rows);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to tell us what the error is?

Comment: Looking at that code, you're probably getting many more errors than just one as you say. Is this your full code? What is the error you have trouble understanding/fixing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "call" of function `sum_matrices` within function `main`...

```
sum_matrices (my_matrix_1[][NUM_COLS], my_matrix_2[][NUM_COLS], num_rows, result[][NUM_COLS]);
```

is a mixture of a forward declaration of a function and a function call, but neither of both is complete or allowed at this position in that form.

To call the function, write...

```
sum_matrices (my_matrix_1, my_matrix_2, num_rows, result);
```